# cant decode a message from a Websocket

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I`m trying to connect my HTML/JS client to my C# server as a part of a university project in order to allow the user real-time notification. (I just need the server to be able to send a specific user a message at any given time)

My server Is just a mock in order to implement it in my project.

I Successfully passed the handshake stage and I am trying to send a plain string from the server to the client. I read something about Encoding the message is a way that the client will not give the "One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1" error but without success.

How can I send primitive data through the Sockets and decode them on the client?

My server code:

```
while (true)
{
    TcpListener sck = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 7878);
    sck.Start(1000);
    TcpClient client = sck.AcceptTcpClient();

    NetworkStream _stream = client.GetStream();
    StreamReader clientStreamReader = new StreamReader(_stream);
    StreamWriter clientStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(_stream);
    while (true)
    {
        while (!_stream.DataAvailable) ;
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[client.Available];
        _stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Count());
        String data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

        if (Regex.IsMatch(data, "^GET"))
        {
            const string eol = "\r\n"; // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker

            Byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + eol
                + "Connection: Upgrade" + eol
                + "Upgrade: websocket" + eol
                + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                            new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(data).Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
                            )
                        )
                    ) + eol
                + eol);

            _stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My Client Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebSocketTest() {
    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

        // Let us open a web socket
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7878");

        ws.onopen = function () {

            // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
            ws.send("Message to send");
            alert("Message is sent...");
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            var received_msg = evt.data;
            alert("Message is received...");
        };

        ws.onclose = function () {

            // websocket is closed.
            alert("Connection is closed...");
        };
    } else {

         // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
         alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
     }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you use third-party libraries?

Comment: I can do as I wish....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SuperWebSocket](https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperWebSocket), this library sends the handshake automatically.

Server:

```
using SuperSocket.SocketBase;
using SuperWebSocket;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Jees.Library.WebSocket
{
    public class WebSocket
    {
        WebSocketServer appServer;

        public event EventHandler ServerStarted;
        public event EventHandler ServerStopped;
        public event EventHandler MessageReceived;

        public string IP { get; } = string.Empty;
        public int Port { get; } = 1337; //change this to the port you want to use

        public WebSocket() => this.IP = GetLocalIPAddress(); //or set it manually

        public void Start()
        {
            appServer = new WebSocketServer();
            if (!appServer.Setup(this.IP, this.Port))
            {
                this.OnServerStarted(new WebSocketServerEventArgs(false));
                return;
            }
            /* start listening */
            appServer.NewMessageReceived += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession, string>(AppServer_NewMessageReceived);
            if (appServer.Start())
                this.OnServerStarted(new WebSocketServerEventArgs(true));
            else
            {
                this.OnServerStarted(new WebSocketServerEventArgs(false));
                appServer = null;
                appServer.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (appServer != null)
            {
                appServer.Stop();
                this.OnServerStopped(new EventArgs());
                appServer = null;
                appServer.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void AppServer_NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string message)
        {
            this.OnMessageReceived(new MessageReceivedEventArgs(message, session));
        }

        protected virtual void OnMessageReceived(EventArgs e) => this.MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, e);

        protected virtual void OnServerStarted(EventArgs e) => this.ServerStarted?.Invoke(this, e);

        protected virtual void OnServerStopped(EventArgs e) => this.ServerStopped?.Invoke(this, e);

        private string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    return ip.ToString();
            throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
        }
    }

    public class WebSocketServerEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public WebSocketServerEventArgs(bool success) => this.Success = success;
        public bool Success { get; }
    }

    public class MessageReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public MessageReceivedEventArgs(string message, WebSocketSession session)
        {
            this.Message = message;
            this.Session = session;
        }
        public string Message { get; }
        public WebSocketSession Session { get; }
    }
}
```

Server Setup (I use a `UserControl`):

```cs
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using SuperWebSocket;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebSocketServer
{
    public partial class Server : UserControl
    {
        WebSocket server;
        WebSocketSession session;

        public Server()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            server = new WebSocket();
            server.ServerStarted += Server_ServerStarted;
            server.ServerStopped += Server_ServerStopped;
            server.MessageReceived += Server_MessageReceived;
        }

        private void Server_MessageReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageReceivedEventArgs eventArgs = (MessageReceivedEventArgs)e;
            /* save session */
            this.session = eventArgs.Session;
            this.Log("SessionID: " + session.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "; Message: " + eventArgs.Message);
            /* send back the message to the client */
            this.session.Send(eventArgs.Message); //comment out if needed
        }

        private void Server_ServerStopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Log("Server stopped!");
        }

        private void Server_ServerStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e as WebSocketServerEventArgs).Success)
            {
                this.Log("Server started on ws://" + server.IP + ":" + server.Port + "/");
            }
            else
                this.Log("Can't start the server!");
        }

        private void Log(string message)
        {
            /* here, this.log is a TextBox */
            if (this.log.InvokeRequired)
                this.log.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    this.log.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + " > " + message + Environment.NewLine;
                });
            else
            {
                this.log.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + " > " + message + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        /* a button to start the server */
        private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => server.Start();

        /* a button to stop the server */
        private void BtnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => server.Stop();

        /* a button to send a message from a TextBox to the client */
        private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.txtMessage.Text != string.Empty)
                this.SendMessage(this.txtMessage.Text);
        }

        private void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                /* use current session to send the message */
                this.session.Send(message);
                this.Log("Message: " + message + " sent to client!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.Log(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more clarification, add a comment and I'll update my answer!

Comment: I Would love some more information about how to connect the  SuperWebSocket sln, to my sln of the naive server. and also from my understanding the WebSocket part in the EventHandler part of the spacific WebSocket, But i don`t understande how the connection is made in the Server, The functionalty in the server is great to understand the way to use it, I can remove the parts that are irrelevant to me like the btn Handlers and recieving a message from the user. Thanks a lot for thehelp

Comment: @YairLandmann build the SuperWebSocket solution and on the /bin/debug/ folder, take the libraries SuperSocket.Common.dll, SuperSocket.SocketBase.dll, SuperSocket.SocketEngine.dll, SuperWebSocket.dll, log4net.dll and add them as references on your project

Comment: Great that helped a lot; sorry for my ignorance.. And can you explain to me what is the purpose of the UserControl?

Comment: @YairLandmann its prupose is just to have an UI to start / stop the server, see the received and sent messages and send messages to the client

Comment: Is there an easy way to remove the need for the UI so i can start the server just by calling a function? I see that in class WebSocket i get errors in the lines:
 if (!appServer.Setup(this.IP, this.Port)), appServer.NewMessageReceived += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession, string>(AppServer_NewMessageReceived); appServer.Dispose();                   And on the server i get errors on the log parts and the txtMessage part (because i dont want to use a ui in me server)

Answer (score 1):

I kept my server as above but added a send string function, and a decode message function:

```
public static string DecodeMessage(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        string incomingData = string.Empty;
        byte secondByte = bytes[1];
        int dataLength = secondByte & 127;
        int indexFirstMask = 2;
        if (dataLength == 126)
            indexFirstMask = 4;
        else if (dataLength == 127)
            indexFirstMask = 10;

        IEnumerable<byte> keys = bytes.Skip(indexFirstMask).Take(4);
        int indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4;

        byte[] decoded = new byte[bytes.Length - indexFirstDataByte];
        for (int i = indexFirstDataByte, j = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++, j++)
        {
            decoded[j] = (byte)(bytes[i] ^ keys.ElementAt(j % 4));
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);
    }

public static void SendString(string userName ,string str)
    {
        if (!userConnections.ContainsKey(userName))
            return;
        TcpClient client = userConnections[userName];
        NetworkStream _stream = client.GetStream();

        try
        {

            var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
            int frameSize = 64;

            var parts = buf.Select((b, i) => new { b, i })
                            .GroupBy(x => x.i / (frameSize - 1))
                            .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.b).ToArray())
                            .ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count; i++)
            {
                byte cmd = 0;
                if (i == 0) cmd |= 1;
                if (i == parts.Count - 1) cmd |= 0x80;

                _stream.WriteByte(cmd);
                _stream.WriteByte((byte)parts[i].Length);
                _stream.Write(parts[i], 0, parts[i].Length);
            }

            _stream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }


    }
```

Where  userConnections is:       public static Dictionary userConnections = new Dictionary();
in order to maintain user - connection relation